# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on Classic Load Balancer AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have a `classic load balancer` that reads from both port 80 (http) and 433 (https) for my elastic beanstalk application. I have correctly setup an SSL certificate and everything works properly with my custom domain.

However, when I search for my domain: `mydomain.com` it automatically uses `http` instead of `https`. How can I allow it to use https automatically?

Edit: I am trying to deploy a django application.

New to this so let me know if I am leaving out some information.

Comment: With a classic load balancer, you have to do this in your application. Is there a reason that you're using a classic ELB? If there is, you should edit your question to let people know that, and also what language/framework you're using to deploy (because nobody can answer without knowing that).

Comment: Edited my answer. Deploying a django app. What else would I use?

Comment: Just wanted to follow up, really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not tied to a Classic Load Balancer, I recommend switching to an [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html): it will give you much more control over how you route requests, and supports HTTP->HTTPS redirect out of the box (doc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#redirect-actions) although you'll probably want to read the rest of that page and work through one of the tutorials to understand the context).

If you are tied to the Classic ELB then you'll have to do the redirect in your client code. I'm not familiar with Django, but [it seems straightforward](https://serverfault.com/a/907669). The prior answer on that question shows how to do it if you have `nginx` in front of Django.

Comment: Thank you for your response!! Right now, i used this tutorial to deploy my django app: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html --- do you know how I could switch from classic to application?? Thanks!!

Comment: [This doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html) indicates that Elastic Beanstalk creates an ALB by default, so you should be able to go into the Console and reconfigure it. Can't tell you how to change the Elastic Beanstalk configuration though.

Comment: I think I figured it out. When running ebcreate django_proj you need to just run ebcreate as you can then select Application Load Balancer. Trying it now!!

Comment: @JannickeTvedt EBS doesn't allow you to update your load balancer type but you can define it while initializing your application by using `--elb-type type` option. Valid values: `classic, application, network`. If you can't create a new project then you need to configure your webserver conf file in the `.ebextensions` for a classic load balancer.